# How to filter post by join condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `wpps_posts` which have this structure:

```
ID | post_title | post_type
 1      foo         zoacres-property
 2      foo2        zoacres-property
 3      foo3        post
```

I would like to return all the posts with type `zoacres-property` and also I want filter them by price. Each price is stored inside the table `wp_postmeta`:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
  100       2         price       5000 
  100       1         price       0
```

How can I order all the posts by price `ASC`?

I'm stuck with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM wpps_posts p
INNER JOIN wpps_posts wp ON wp.ID = p.ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'zoacres-property'
ORDER BY wp.meta??
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
ID | post_title | post_type
 1      foo         zoacres-property
 2      foo2        zoacres-propertY
```

Comment: Show us the expected result as well. (And perhaps a few more rows than 2 could make the problem clearer.)

Comment: @jarlh I've updated the question and fixed the example, thanks

Comment: Where is the `wpps_posts` table? It is `posts` table ?

Comment: Let try `SELECT * FROM wpps_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp ON p.ID = wp.post_id
WHERE p.post_type = 'zoacres-property'
ORDER BY wp.meta_value ASC`

Comment: You need to JOIN the table with the price too.

Comment: @HtetPhyoNaing yes, I just added a prefix for security reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this, depends what other type of meta type records you have.

```
SELECT * FROM wpps_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wpps_posts.ID AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'price'
WHERE wpps_posts.post_type = 'zoacres-property'
ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM wpps_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp ON wp.post_ID = p.ID
AND wp.meta_key='price'
WHERE p.post_type = 'zoacres-property'
ORDER BY wp.meta_value asc
```